# In RethinkDB, what is the easiest way to check if a database or a table exists?

Tags: rethinkdb

One way I know I can do it is by listing through`dbList()` and `tableList()` and then looking for what I want in the results.

Is there an easier way?

**EDIT**

My goal is to create a table in case it doesn't exist.

Comment: for example you can try to create table, if it's already exists, you will see error: RqlRuntimeError: Table  already exists

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? Do you want to create a database if it doesn't exist, or simply check if it exists?

Comment: @Suvitruf, thanks for the reply. I wasn't really interested in throwing an error.. I just wanted to check whether it existed.

Comment: @Tholle, yes. I want to create a table in case it doesn't exist.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

If you want to create a database if it does not exists, or get a value like "database already exists" if it does exist, you could do something like the following:

```
r.dbList().contains('example_database')
  .do(function(databaseExists) {
    return r.branch(
      databaseExists,
      { dbs_created: 0 },
      r.dbCreate('example_database')
    );
  }).run();
```

It will return the following if it is created:

```
{
  "config_changes": [
    {
      "new_val": {
        "id": "1ee7ddb4-6e2c-43bb-a0f5-64ef6a6211a8",
        "name": "example_database"
      },
      "old_val": null
    }
  ],
  "dbs_created": 1
}
```

And this if it already exists:

```
{
  "dbs_created": 0
}
```

Comment: @Tholle why so complicated? my version with python: `for table in self.tables:
     if not rdb.db(self.db).table_list().contains(table).run():
     rdb.db(self.db).table_create(table).run()`

Answer (score 7):

For the table existing checking I have found the following solution:

```
r.tableList().run(connection); //['people']
```

this will give you back an array of the tables which are defined on the default DB for example: ['people']. (if you want to set it do this: connection.use('test');)

then we can check if the array is containing our table name to create.

```
_.some(tableNames, tableName)
```

put it all together:

```
  if (!_.isNil(tableName) && _.isString(tableName) && !_.isNil(connection)) {
    r.tableList().run(connection).then(function(tableNames) {
      if (_.includes(tableNames, tableName)) {
        return r.tableCreate(tableName).run(connection);
      } else {
        return;
        }
    });
  }
```

Answer (score 2):

In JavaScript, given an array of table names, the shortest way is

```
const tables = ['table1Name', 'table2Name', ...]
const db = 'myDb'

r(tables)
    .difference(r.db(db).tableList())
    .forEach(table => r.db(db).tableCreate(table))
    .run(connection)
```

Comment: Don't you need a `run()` after `r.db(db).tableList()` ?

Comment: No you only need to call run at the end of your entire query

Answer (score 0):

For anyone coming from VB.net then solution would be like this.. one liner

```
Dim RDBDatabase as String = "dbName" 
Dim RDBTable as String = "tableName"  
   
Dim CheckDB = R.DbList().Contains(RDBDatabase).Do_(Function(databaseExists) R.Branch(databaseExists, "db done", R.DbCreate(RDBDatabase))).And(R.Db(RDBDatabase).TableList().Contains(RDBTable).Do_(Function(tableExists) R.Branch(tableExists, "tb done", R.Db(RDBDatabase).TableCreate(RDBTable)))).Run(conn)
```

This will create DB if it doesn't exists and will create the table if it doesn't exist

If neither exists then it will return values from the last created which is the table

```
{{
  "config_changes": [
    {
      "new_val": {
        "db": "dbName",
        "durability": "hard",
        "id": "0f72a570-7998-49f7-affc-96cbdd1ea086",
        "indexes": [],
        "name": "tableName",
        "primary_key": "id",
        "shards": [
          {
            "nonvoting_replicas": [],
            "primary_replica": "replicasssss_iu1",
            "replicas": [
              "replicasssss_iu1"
            ]
          }
        ],
        "write_acks": "majority"
      },
      "old_val": null
    }
  ],
  "tables_created": 1
}}
```