# RethinkDB Java: how to check whether a table already exists?

Tags: java, rethinkdb

If I attempt to create a table like:

```
r.tableCreate("mytable").optArg("primary_key", "id").run(conn);
```

It will throw an exception if **mytable** already exists.

My question is simple: is there a more appropriate procedure to determine whether a table already exists other than try/catch the exception? E.g. a method returning a boolean value or a method that creates only if not exists.

Thank you for your attention

**edit:** regarding [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31633322/4828060), the methods r.dbList() and r.tableList() did not return any information regarding the tables. In line with this, the methods r.tableList().contains() and r.dbList().contains() do not return an answer to my question. Note that I am using the following Java lib:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.rethinkdb</groupId>
  <artifactId>rethinkdb-driver</artifactId>
  <version>2.3.3</version>
</dependency>
```

and I am not sure if the above-mentioned methods from this library are meant to be equivalent to those mentioned in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31633322/4828060).

Comment: is this from a specific library/framework?

Comment: not sure if I understood the question, I imported rethinkdb-driver (com.rethinkdb) as a maven dependency.

Comment: so basically this is a question about rethinkdb? have you checked it's documentation?

Comment: I think this is exactly what you are looking for: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31625913/in-rethinkdb-what-is-the-easiest-way-to-check-if-a-database-or-a-table-exists

Comment: yes, I found no answer to my specific question

Comment: Check the link I commented

Comment: Possible duplicate of [In RethinkDB, what is the easiest way to check if a database or a table exists?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31625913/in-rethinkdb-what-is-the-easiest-way-to-check-if-a-database-or-a-table-exists)

Comment: yes I had already seen that answer, unfortunately the method r.dbList().contains('example_database') and the method r.tableList().contains('example_database'), do not have the expected outpt

Comment: not sure if this is relevant or not but that answer is not for java, maybe a limitation of the rethinkdb java lib ?

Comment: _r.tableList() did not return any information regarding the tables_ this seems hardly conceivable... What was the information returned? _and the method r.tableList().contains('example_database'), do not have the expected outpt_ then what are you expecting and what did you get instead? (Hoping trying a _table_ named _example_database_ was a typo.)